# How to get response from other user after joining room using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

i have one doubt regarding socket.io.I have two type of user `i.e-admin,client` .First admin will create userid  and join to the room.I need when user will join room the admin should get response and need help regarding this.

My working codes are given below.

> server.js:

```
var port=8888;
var express=require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var http=require('http');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var mongo = require('mongojs');
var database='Oditek';
var collections=['video'];
var app= express();
var server=http.Server(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(server);
var db = mongo.connect("127.0.0.1:27017/"+database, collections);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));     // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                     // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json())    // parse application/json
app.use(methodOverride());                  // simulate DELETE and PUT
db.on('ready', function () {
    console.log('database connected')
});
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('view/login.html');
});
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    var username=req.body.username;
    var password=req.body.userpassword;
    if(username && password){
        db.video.findOne({
            username:username,
            password:password
        },function(err,doc){
            if(doc){
                console.log('login',doc);
                res.send(doc);
            }
            if(err){
                console.log('login12',err);
                res.send("could not login");
            }
        });
    }
});
app.get('/video',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('view/video.html');
});

//socket----programming//
var roomid;
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    //console.log(socket);
    roomid=socket.handshake.query.roomid;
    var usertype=socket.handshake.query.usertype;
    socket.join(roomid);

});
server.listen(port);
console.log('server is listening on the port'+port);
```

My client side code is given below.

```
function videoBroadCasting(uType){
    var messageGateWay;
    if(uType=='admin'){
        var userid = getRandomString();
        $('#styled').val('http://localhost:8888/video?usertype=client & id='+userid);
        messageGateWay=io('http://localhost:8888/?roomid='+userid+'usertype='+uType);
    }
    if(uType=='user'){
        messageGateWay=io('http://localhost:8888/?usertype='+uType);
    }
    messageGateWay.on('connect',function(){
        console.log('socket get connected');

    });
}
function getRandomString() {
   return (Math.random() * new Date().getTime()).toString(36).replace(/\./g, '');
}
function getQuery(key){
        var temp = location.search.match(new RegExp(key + "=(.*?)($|\&)", "i"));
        if(!temp) return;
        return temp[1];
}
```

After client is joining the room the admin should get one notification.Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to save the socket object from the admin in the server when the admin joins the room. Then, when some other user join the room, simply emit a message to that socket from the admin/admins. Just keep an array update with the admins actually logged in the room.

Something like:

```
var socketAdmin = {};
io.on('adminJoins',function(socket){
  socketAdmin = socket;
  roomid=socket.handshake.query.roomid;
  var usertype=socket.handshake.query.usertype;
  socket.join(roomid);
});
io.on('clientJoins',function(socket){
  roomid=socket.handshake.query.roomid;
  socketAdmin.emit('newClient', {socketClient: socket, roomId: roomid};
  var usertype=socket.handshake.query.usertype;
  socket.join(roomid);
});
```

In this example, the client sends a message 'adminJoins' if you are an admin, or 'clientJoins' ir you are a client, you can send that checking the uType var you have. In case a new client joins the room, the admin recieve a 'newClient' message with the socket of the client and the roomId (just an example).

Comment: Added some code to explain myself better, hope it helps

Comment: Ok,I will try this and let you know later.

Comment: socket will hold only the messages that are coming from client/admin.How it will be `roomid=socket.handshake.query.roomid;`.